# How to remove partitioning by table wildcards in BigQuery and sort by stings

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a few tables in data set with similar name able to union it by wildcards
[image]

I want to aggregate all data from these tables and sort each group by `stage_num`
My expected output must be like this
[image]

I run query:

`SELECT DISTINCT source, code, stage_num FROM atv3.myproject.table_* ORDER BY source, stage_num`
But query returns result partitioned by existing tables and without global sorting

[image]

I tried `PARTITON BY` statement but result seems like partitioning inside each table.
What i do wrong and jow to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your tables and I am not sure why your results for that query have stage_num unsorted, since it appears to be work fine for me. Was that the full query?

However that query unordered the codes. In order to have the results also grouped by codes I ran this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT source, code, stage_num FROM table_* ORDER BY source, code, CAST(stage_num as INT64)
```

Let me know in case it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I was a problem cuz stage_num is string. Need to ORDER BY CAST(stage_num as INT64)